# Using css variables with php in joomla 3 template

Tags: php, css, templates, joomla3.0

My idea is to use template parameter in joomla to set the color for a background, text or buttons.
I want to define a css class instead of each time using style="background-color:`<?php echo $buttoncolor ?>`;" as I don't want to write countless template overrides.

I believe that could be very usefull feature.

The parameter in my templateDetails.xml looks like

```
<field name="buttoncolor" type="color" default="#309000"
                    label="TPL_BUTTON_COLOR_LABEL"
                    description="TPL_BUTTON_COLOR_DESC" />
```

The idea how to use php variable in css I found on  [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/)

To use a php variable within a css I linked to this file in my index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/style.php" type="text/css"  />
```

My style.php looks like:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$buttoncolor = $this->params->get("buttoncolor");
?>

.buttoncolor {background-color: <?php echo $this->params->get('buttoncolor'); ?>;}
```

Usally I set a variable to a template parameter in the index.php like

```
<?php 
//parameter
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument(); 
$params = $app->getParams();
$buttoncolor = $this->params->get('buttoncolor'); 
?>
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:
Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in style.php

Any ideas, workaround and help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to remove `$this`. Your code has to be:

```
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $template = $app->getTemplate(true);
  $params = $template->params;
  $buttoncolor = $params->get("buttoncolor");
```

Joomla has a specific way to set [css style](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page). You have to do it like:

```
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $style = ".buttoncolor {background-color: ".$buttoncolor."}"; 
  $document->addStyleDeclaration($style);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your solution.
If I understood everything right, then there is no reason to include the style.php

It's working perfectly, I never thought that the solution could be that simple.

Great thanks again.

Comment: Sure this way doesn't need an extra file inclusion. You are welcome!